# How can I fix leaderboard getOtherPosition

Tags: binance

getOtherPosition v1 public was working until few days ago.

Now it shows positions all as null, I believe they changed something in URL or added a header or cookie that I don't know about.

Anyone got fix or any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

They changed the API to https://www.binance.com/bapi/futures/v2/**private**/future/leaderboard/getOtherPosition

Now, you can access traders' positions only after logging in.I’m also trying to find a workaround